# Recursion in an XML schema?

Tags: xsd

I need to create an XML schema that validates a tree structure of an XML document. I don't know exactly the occurrences or depth level of the tree.

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node>
  <attribute/>
  <node>
    <attribute/>
    <node/>      
  </node>
</node>
```

Which is the best way to validate it?  Recursion?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

if you need a recursive type declaration, here is an example that might help:

```
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType"></xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="nodeType">    
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, this defines a recursive schema with only one node named "node" which can be as deep as desired.

Answer (score 44):

XSD does indeed allow for recursion of elements. Here [is a sample for you](https://web.archive.org/web/20140421153734/http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200501/post80430.html)

```
<xsd:element name="section">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="title"/>
      <xsd:element ref="para" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element ref="section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

As you can see the section element contains a child element that is of type section.

Comment: +1 I believe this is a better solution than the accepted one as it permits the recursive element to be a ComplexType.

Comment: @Harriv, XSD (XML schema definition) is not a DTD. For the difference, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544200/what-is-difference-between-xml-schema-and-dtd

Comment: Maybe it's useful to know that you can use the ref attribute only on global elements as pointed out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073265/i-have-error-in-xml-the-element-is-not-declared-xml-error

Comment: `minOccurs="0"` is the key

Comment: URL link is down.

Comment: @giannischristofakis I changed to the wayback machine.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions work great for making root elements recursive. However, in order to make a non-root element recursive without turning it into a valid root element in the process, a slightly different approach is needed.

Let's say you want to define an XML message format for exchanging structured data between nodes in a distributed application. It contains the following elements:

- `<message>` - the root element;
- `<from>` - the message's origin;
- `<to>` - the message's destination;
- `<type>` - the data structure type encoded in the message;
- `<data>` - the data contained in the message.

In order to support complex data types, `<data>` is a recursive element. This makes possible to write messages as below, for sending e.g. a [`geometry_msgs/TwistStamped`](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html) message to a flying drone specifying its linear and angular (i.e. rotating) speeds:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<message xmlns="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0">
  <from>controller:8080</from>
  <to>drone:8080</to>
  <type>geometry_msgs/TwistStamped</type>
  <data name="header">
    <data name="seq">0</data>
    <data name="stamp">
      <data name="sec">1</data>
      <data name="nsec">0</data>
    </data>
    <data name="frame_id">base_link</data>
  </data>
  <data name="twist">
    <data name="linear">
      <data name="x">1.0</data>
      <data name="y">0</data>
      <data name="z">1.0</data>
    </data>
    <data name="angular">
      <data name="x">0.3</data>
      <data name="y">0</data>
      <data name="z">0</data>
    </data>
  </data>
</message>
```

We can easily write an XML schema to validate this format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0"
>
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element ref="data" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem with the schema above is that it makes `<data>` a root element, which means it also validates the document below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data xmlns="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0" name="twist">
  <data name="header">
    <data name="seq">0</data>
    <data name="stamp">
      <data name="sec">1</data>
      <data name="nsec">0</data>
    </data>
    <data name="frame_id">base_link</data>
  </data>
  <data name="twist">
    <data name="linear">
      <data name="x">1.0</data>
      <data name="y">0</data>
      <data name="z">1.0</data>
    </data>
    <data name="angular">
      <data name="x">0.3</data>
      <data name="y">0</data>
      <data name="z">0</data>
    </data>
  </data>
</data>
```

In order to avoid this side-effect, instead of defining the `<data>` element directly at the global level, we first define a `data` type, then define a `data` element of that type inside `message`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="https://stackoverflow.com/message/1.0.0"
>
  <xs:complexType name="data" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="data" type="data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="data" type="data" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Notice that we end up having to define the `<data>` element twice — once inside the `data` type, and again inside `<element>` — but apart a little work duplication this is of no consequence.