# Why DTD is not extensible?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I know that a language is extensible if it allows users to create any tags needed and then describing those tags and their permitted uses.

If I'm not wrong, in this example

**code:**

```
<!ELEMENT people_list (person)*>
<!ELEMENT person (name, birthdate?, gender?, socialsecuritynumber?)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT birthdate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gender (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT socialsecuritynumber (#PCDATA)>
```

The DTD is defining an element (tag) called person, another element called name etc...

So, **why this is not extensible as XSD?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background**: DTD exists to support the *extensibility* of XML.  Instead of
   a fixed markup language, XML allows you to define your own vocabulary
   and grammar via a schema such as DTD.

> Why DTD is not extensible?

### DTD *is* extensible.

- DTDs can be extended via various techniques.  Examples include repeating `ATTLIST` to add attributes and redefining parameter ENTITIES.
- There's a long history of clever DTD extensibility applied to substantial projects.  Examples:

  - **TEI**: The Text Encoding Initiative has [extensible DTDs](http://www.tei-c.org/Vault/P4/doc/p4dtd.html).
  - **XHTML**: See [*Developing DTDs with defined and extended modules*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xhtml-building-20000105/developing.html#s_developingdtds).

> So, **why this is not extensible as XSD?**

Because DTD predates XSD, and **progress occurs**.

### See also

- [Is DTD deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893680/is-dtd-deprecated)

Comment: [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/dtd-vs-xsd) it's mentioned that DTD is not extensible.  It's also mentioned in page 22 of [this](https://www.amazon.com/XML-Programming-Using-Microsoft-Parser/dp/1893115429) book (look [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6bgYAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22dtd+is+not+extensible%22&source=bl&ots=H0etU58RdO&sig=Mw5eQOSHYWePj4Occ8cvspkGMAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAvcyx-trbAhVEWK0KHaD8BRIQ6AEIRjAD#v=onepage&q=%22dtd%20is%20not%20extensible%22&f=false)). And also in [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/integrate.1012/b14069/xsd.htm)

Comment: @KennetCeleste: Seriously?  You down-voted this refined answer based upon decades of experience building real systems using both DTDs and XSDs and cite sweeping one-line generalizations as justification?  Yes, of course, XSDs afford greater flexibility.  As I stated, ***progress occurs***.   If *you're* satisfied with high-level, bullet-pointed generalizations, feel free to limit your understanding to "is-to/is-not" extensible arguments.  Here, I offer a bit more subtle answer and give a glimpse into how projects have achieved a degree of extensibility with DTD.