# I have error in xml the element is not declared xml error

Tags: xml, xsd

II have error in xml the element is not declared xml error. Why I have this error? xsd file
I have xds file and when I write rel an another attribute a ha error

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" `

   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`
     <xsd:element name="TWM_SAD">
       <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Export_release">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Date_of_exit"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Time_of_exit"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Actual_office_of_exit_code"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Actual_office_of_exit_name"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Exit_reference"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Comments"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Assessment_notice">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:short" name="Registration_year"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Assessment_year"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:float" name="Total_item_taxes"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_number"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_date"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_serial"/>


            label      <xsd:element ref="Item"  maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>


            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Item">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_code"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_description"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_amount"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

error is The Item element is not declared? In label I have this error

Answer (score 4):

To be able to reference an element, you have to make it global. In other words, you have to move the declaration of `Item` directly under the `xsd:schema element`. In your case, at the same level as `TWM_SAD`

This is your corrected and syntactically valid XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="TWM_SAD">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Export_release">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Date_of_exit"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Time_of_exit"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Actual_office_of_exit_code"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Actual_office_of_exit_name"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Exit_reference"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Comments"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Assessment_notice">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:short" name="Registration_year"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Assessment_year"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:float" name="Total_item_taxes"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_number"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_date"/>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Statement_serial"/>
                            <xsd:element ref="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            <!--
            <xsd:element ref="Item" />
            -->
            <!--
        <xsd:element name="Item">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_code"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_description"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_amount"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
            -->
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Item">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_code"/>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_description"/>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Tax_amount"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```