# Guaranteed child element at unknown depth with XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema in which I know that an element has to have a particular child, but I do not know the depth at which that child will exist at. Take the following example XML:

```
<node id="top">
   <node id="inner">
     <event/>
   </node>
</node>

<node id="top">
   <event/>
</node>
```

The only requirements I have is that an `<event>` element must be a descendant of the `<node id="top">` element, but I do not know at what depth it will occur. In other words, there could be any number of `<node id="inner">` elements in between the top `<node id="top">` and an `<event>` element. In the example above, each of those are valid within the schema. My attempted solution was:

```
<xs:element name="node">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="node" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="event"/>
                     </xs:sequence>
                   <xs:attribute name="id" fixed="inner"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="id" fixed="top"/>
</xs:element>
```

But, as expected, this does not take into account many "depths" of `<node>` elements that can occur after the `<node id="top">` element.

Comment: Looks like this is mostly a duplicate. The simple answer to this question is that you MUST specify maxOccurs="unbounded" to get unknown recursive depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148988/recursion-in-xsd-schemas)! Try something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://test"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  xmlns:test="http://test"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="nodes">   
      <xs:complexType> 
           <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                   <xs:element name="node"  type="test:nodeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="nodeType">  
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                           <xs:element name="event" minOccurs="0"/>
                           <xs:element name="node" type="test:nodeType" minOccurs="0">

</xs:schema>
```