# How to create the xsd schema for tree of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have the class:

```
class Node{
    Public string Name;
    Public Node LeftNode;
    Public Node RightNode;
}
```

With that class I am able to create a tree of nodes and I will like to represent that tree with xml.

Currently my XML schema looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Node" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>

                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />

                <xs:element name="RightNode">    
                    <!-- I need help here -->
                 </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="LeftNode">    
                    <!-- I need help here -->
                 </xs:element>

            </xs:all>   
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks to that I have intellicence in visual studio and I am able to create the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<Node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Path_Where_Xsd_File_IsLocated.xsd">

  <Name>Test></Name>    
  <RightNode></RightNode>    
  <LeftNode></LeftNode>

</Node>
```

**The problem that I am having is that I will like to be able to have nested children. In other words I will like to be able to construct something like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<Node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Path_Where_Xsd_File_IsLocated.xsd">

  <Name>Test></Name>    
  <RightNode>
       <Node>
           <Name>SomeChildName</Name>
       </Node>
  </RightNode>    
  <LeftNode></LeftNode>

</Node>
```

I am able to construct that three but when I start typing the child nodes, intellicence will not work as well as any validation that I want to perform on the xml.

I have tried the following:

```
<xsd:element name="RightNode" >
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
             <xs:element ref="Node">  
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**How can I fix my xml schema (xsd file) so that intellicence continues to work with child nodes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a recursive XSD.  Here's an example that may work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Node" type="Node"/>

<xs:complexType name="Node">
   <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="RightNode" type="Node"/>
      <xs:element name="LeftNode" type="Node"/>
   </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

You can find another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148988/recursion-in-xsd-schemas) that covers general recursion within XSDs.