# How to express a recursive array and subtypes in XML XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

My goal is to have an element  that can contain any number of shape elements (circle, rectangle, triangle). I am completely new to XML and XSD and am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Basically I want it to validate the following

```
<array>
    <circle/>
    <circle/>
    <triangle/>
    <circle/>
</array>
```

I would also like the array to contain further arrays. Can you express this in XSD in some way? So I can validate something like this

```
<array>
    <circle/>
    <circle/>
    <array>
        <rectangle/>
    </array>
    <triangle/>
    <circle/>
</array>
```

So to sum up:

- Can I make an element type shape and then have the different types as sub-types?
- Can I do array elements recursively?

Comment: Here is a [related similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148988/recursion-in-an-xml-schema) for info about the recursive part.